# JS + DharmaProtocol - Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '...' does not provide an export named 'Dharma'

Tags: javascript, dependencies, ethereum

I am in the process of building a relayer with the Dharma Protocol. When attempting to import the protocol (installed via yarn add @dharmaprotocol/dharma.js) I receive the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 
'./node_modules/@dharmaprotocol/dharma.js/dist/lib/src/index.js' does not 
provide an export named 'Dharma'
```

I have tried renaming the index.js file located in the directory of "node_modules/@dharmaprotocol/dharma.js/dist/lib/src/" to index.mjs in hopes of  JS recognizing it as a module file but found no success.

mint.js:

```
import { Dharma } from "@dharmaprotocol/dharma.js";
const provider = window.web3.currentProvider;
provider.enable();
const dharma = new Dharma(provider);
```

index.js:

```
"use strict";
/***********
 *  Utils  *
 ***********/
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
// Allows the user to instantiate the correct version of BigNumber.js 
without
// needing to add version 5.0.0 to their project.
var bignumber_1 = require("../utils/bignumber");
exports.BigNumber = bignumber_1.BigNumber;
var Web3 = require("web3");
exports.Web3 = Web3;
/***********
 *  Types  *
 ***********/
var dharma_1 = require("./types/dharma");
exports.Dharma = dharma_1.Dharma;
```